# How to improve this nested select statment

Tags: mysql

How to improve this nested select statement because i think it has bad performance because I see it take a long time to execute and gets the server load high

```
SELECT user_tagtag,
user_lastcontentid,
(SELECT COUNT( content_id )  
 FROM contents 
 WHERE contents.content_id > user_lastcontentid AND 
       contents.content_id IN ( 
         SELECT contenttag_contentid 
         FROM contents_vs_tags 
         WHERE contenttag_tagtag = user_tagtag 
       ) 
) AS tag_newnews_no
FROM users_interests_tags  
WHERE user_userid = 1 
ORDER BY user_tagsorder ASC
```

users_interests_tags  table structure is:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_userid        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_tagtag        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_lastcontentid | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

contents table structure is:

```
+---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| content_id          | bigint(20)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content_title       | varchar(255)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

contents_vs_tags table structure is:

```
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| contenttag_contentid | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| contenttag_tagtag    | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

where `contents_vs_tags.contenttag_contentid` is a index and foreign key of contents.content_id

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See JOINs. They're a fundamental concept of relational databases.

Answer (score 3):

Often a correlated subquery (one where it must be executed for every row, and thus causing huge performance problems) can be converted into a join, and your query falls into this category:

```
SELECT
    user_tagtag,
    user_lastcontentid,
    COUNT( distinct content_id ) AS tag_newnews_no
FROM users_interests_tags
LEFT JOIN contents_vs_tags ON contenttag_tagtag = user_tagtag
LEFT JOIN contents ON contents.content_id = contenttag_contentid
WHERE user_userid = 1
AND contents.content_id > user_lastcontentid
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY user_tagsorder
```

By using LEFT JOIN, tags without matching rows will still be returned, but with zero for their count.

Note the use of `distinct` to get the same results your query is returning.

This will perform *significantly* better than your query (and significantly better than the other answer!) because all access is directly from the tsbles, rather thsn via subqueries.

Make sure you have indexes on the key columns:

```
CREATE INDEX contents_vs_tags_1 ON contents_vs_tags(contenttag_tagtag);
CREATE INDEX contents_1 ON contents(content_id);
```

Comment: but this query return just 1 tag not all tags for the userid 1

Comment: thanks for help but i test the query it work but it just return 1 tag for the user , not all his tags from the table users_interests_tags, is there any way to modify it to return all of his tags

Comment: Oops no problem thanks for help, but still not showing all tags , it just show 3 tags from total 5 , note that WHERE user_userid =1 here 1 is dynamically come from $uid , so any advice?

Comment: yes yes its ok , its not show the other 2 tags because there is no result for it. understood , thanks I will test the statement now under pressure.

Comment: If you need all tags, but with zero counts if they don't satisfy all conditions, left me know

Comment: Also, try to get in to the habit of properly identifying ALL returned columns - it makes your code much clearer (for both us humans and, in some instances, mysql itself) - just like you did with `contents.content_id`. And then try to get in to the habit of aliasing your tables, so `contents.content_id` might become `c.content_id`.

Comment: is there anyway to return all tags in users_interests_tags   table even if the tag has not (tag_newnews_no) because the current above query just show the tags which have tag_newnews_no , but if the tag is not have tag_newnews_no did not returned. so is there any way to do that?

Comment: yes it will help me much more if i can return all tage that have zero counts and non zero counts. because the current query just return the tags with non zero counts.

Comment: OK I've changed the query to use *outer* joins (via the LEFT keyword). Outer joins still return rows from the first table in the FROM clause even if there are no matching rows for them. See edited query in answer.

Comment: the query with LEFT keyword take 23 second to execute while it was executing with les than 0.01 second without LEFT. any advice?

Comment: Have you crates indexes as per those at the end of the answer?

Comment: yes i create the indexes exactly. still have the query time more than 20 seconds with the LEFT JOIN and less than 0.5 second without the LEFT. thanks verymuch for your help i will use it without left and then make another query to get non exists tags from the other query.

Comment: I've made yet another change. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a index for your tags.

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_tag` ON users_interests_tags (user_tagtag(10));
```

and also

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_tag` ON contents_vs_tags (contenttag_tagtag(10));
```

For your query:

```
SELECT t1.user_tagtag, t1.user_lastcontentid,
    (
        SELECT COUNT( t2.content_id )  
        FROM contents t2
        INNER JOIN contents_vs_tags t3 ON (t3.contenttag_tagtag = t1.user_tagtag)
        WHERE t2.content_id > t1.user_lastcontentid 
            AND t3.contenttag_tagtag = t1.user_tagtag 
    ) AS tag_newnews_no
FROM users_interests_tags t1
WHERE t1.user_userid = 1 
ORDER BY t1.user_tagsorder ASC
```

Probably you'll still have problems with your ORDER BY once the column is not indexed. It can give you temporary tables and filesort.

Keep an eye on that and use EXPLAIN to check out how to improve it even more.